# How to access to thymeleaf template page in web application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf to create a template for my web page and Spring. Here is the configuration in Spring app-servlet.xml :

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />
</bean>
```

I have also a Controller with method :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";

    }
}
```

Here is the html page in webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
      <title>Spring MVC Example</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div th:include="templates/fragments/header::header"></div>
      <h1>Hello on a second page!</h1>
      <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to go back.</p>
      <div th:include="templates/fragments/footer::footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When i access to home page `http://localhost:8080/app-web` i have the following error :

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [app] in context with path [/app-web] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'app'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'app'
```

I don't understand because in Dispatcher, i load app-servlet.xml in which i have templateEngine and templateViewResolver which is configured in the directory WEB-INF/views and the .html extension. 
If someone could help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the error. The bean ThymeleafResolver was in error. The errors is about i defined two times the view name. Firstly, in bean templateResolver were i specified its suffix (.html). Secondly, defined in ThymeleafViewResolver bean below where i used *.html and *.xhtml.

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    **<property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />**
</bean>
```

After

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```